# Microsoft Graph Subscription API started returning HTTP 308 with no Location

Tags: api, microsoft-graph-api, webhooks

We have some production code that deletes an existing subscription in certain cases. We started getting a HTTP 308 response to certain DELETE requests but we can't identify why this is occurring or what the relevance of the 308 is. There doesn't seem to be any information on a 308 in the Graph Docs; HTTP specs indicates this is a permanent redirect. There is no location header provided.

Our request is pretty simple:

`DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/c9ec8a0f-0c9d-492c-90a8-2b0bb96b11d8`

We included the content type and the Authorization header. The response in full:

```
HTTP/1.1 308 
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/plain
request-id: 4430ff3b-3eff-44c6-aafc-1527cd01817b
client-request-id: 4430ff3b-3eff-44c6-aafc-1527cd01817b
x-ms-ags-diagnostic: {"ServerInfo":{"DataCenter":"South Central US","Slice":"SliceC","Ring":"3","ScaleUnit":"000","RoleInstance":"AGSFE_IN_20"}}
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
Date: Tue, 11 Aug 2020 12:04:17 GMT
Content-Length: 0
```

There is no error object or code that I can see as indicated by MS Graph Errors page. We have seen this error several thousand times but seems to be specific to certain subscriptions. I'm not sure where to go with this.

Comment: I did some further debugging on this. I just want to clarify, the subscription does exist, and the delete always returns a 308. Effectively, there is no way to delete these subscriptions.

Comment: I'm almost certain this must be a platform bug. It started without precedent, we have released no code in months that impact this, and I was able to manually re-create the process.

1. Create a subscription.
2. Delete the subscription in the format above. 
3. It always returns 308 with no location and no details.

Comment: I opened a corresponding ticket regarding the documentation being incorrect.

https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9609

Comment: This appears to be account specific. On those same users, we cannot create a subscription either, the same error occurs, 308.