# 308 for some tenants when creating subscriptions for OneDrive

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I have a multi-tenant app serving dozens of different tenants.

Since 4 days ago (14/11/20) I started receiving 308 status code on requests to create subscriptions for **all users** in **some of the tenants**, while other tenants were not affected (they are working fine - subscriptions can be both renewed and created).

Nothing changed on my end and again - for the majority of users it works fine.

There's no content in the response body, only 308.

This happen only to drive-subscriptions, I also have mail-subscriptions for the same tenant and they work fine.

The request I'm doing is a `POST` request to the [subscriptions endpoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http): `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions/`

I don't have a requestId as I'm getting an empty response body and 308 status code from Microsoft Graph.

I tried looking in the health section in admin center but all seems fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: (1) For which Graph API calls you see this failure in your subscription (say, delete a file in onedrive)?  (2) Share the detailed error log, timestamp, requestid.

Comment: (3) Did the subscription got created/recreated? (4) Did the proper event occur? (5) Does the above API call work in Microsoft Graph Explorer?

Comment: (1) What? I can't create a subscription, that's the whole issue. What do you mean "..in your subscription.."? (2) I don't have a request Id, empty response from Microsoft (3) The subscription isn't created. (4) not sure what you mean (5) yes.

Comment: I remember a related issue reported earlier... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63428828/microsoft-graph-subscription-api-started-returning-http-308-with-no-location

Comment: Also here is the related doc bug filed - https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/9609

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after about a month I think I have an explanation.
It seems like the `resource` part of the `create subscription` request has been changed and that the change was made in steps, i.e. for some tenants, the old resource still worked and for some it didn't.

The new resource that should be specified for OneDrive subscriptions is `users/{user_id}/drive/root` while the old one was `drives/{user_id}/root`.

At this point, the old version only works for about 5% of the tenants I'm interacting with, for all the rest I get 308 with empty body if I try to use the old one.

[Graph Subscriptions Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/subscription-post-subscriptions?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: I saw today that we stopped getting new webhooks, and found out that we got for a while status 308 when trying to create new subscriptions, I end up finding the solution myself but after I fixed our production environment, I had to check if other developers were affected by this change as well